# Magento2: How to add dependency in composer for private Gitlab modules?

Tags: magento2, composer, git, dependency

I'm installing a custom module in M2 using composer from my private Gitlab repo and it is working fine.

After I've added the dependency of other modules(using composer require) in my custom module which placed in the same private Gitlab but it is not working with the **composer require test/module-test-extended:dev-master --ignore-platform-reqs** command.

ERROR:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
Problem 1
 - Installation request for test/module-test-extended dev-master -> satisfiable by test/module-test-extended[dev-master].
 - test/module-test-extended dev-master requires test/module-test dev-master -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

Composer.json

```
{
  "name": "test/module-test-extended",
  "description": "Test Module",
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
  ],
  "require": {
    "test/module-test":"dev-master"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://vcs.xxx.com/test/module-test"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Note: Implementing composer dependency without packagist**

Comment: have you added the repo in your composer json? the dependency is not sufficeint

Comment: @PhilippSander please check the update description.

Answer (score 1):

it's just about your php version not about dependencies you can just ignore php version using --ignore-platform-reqs

so you run something like

composer update --ignore-platform-reqs

Comment: I've checked above command. Please check the updated description.